# How do I discover the Quarter in a fiscal year

Tags: custom-fiscal-year

Can any one help me out.How can i get the Quarters in a Fiscal Year.
Im looking Something in this way :
1)

```
Quarter 1 = JAN+FEB+MAR;

Quarter 2 = APR+MAY+JUN;

Quarter 3 = JUl+AUG+SEP;

Quarter 4 = OCT+NOV+DEC;

for the past , present and future years.Do we have any standard formula or need to go with the logics.
```

2)Apart from this ,do we have an option in the Quarters for the Row to get calculated and display the result.Similarly in the Column.

```
Name  Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 GrandTotal
A      1 2   3  4  (sum of q1+q2+q3+q4)10
B      5 10 15 20  (sum of q1+q2+q3+q4)50
total  6 12 18 24   60 60
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

> Update
>
> used Group By clause in my soql query

```
[SELECT gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c,sum(gmod__Price__c) gmod__Price__c ,SUm(gmod__Amount__c) gmod__Amount__c,Sum(gmod__Quantity__c) gmod__Qunatity__c,COUNT(id) Quantity 
  FROM gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c 
  WHERE gmod__date__c=THIS_FISCAL_YEAR GROUP BY gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c];
```

> but at the gmod__date__c its not accepting the Last Fiscal year .
>
> It doesnot gives the o/p and the grandtotal is not dispalyed
>   correctly.

Comment: You can use SOQL to retrieve Grouped resultset using [Date Functions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm) and Group By clause..

Comment: @VarunC:I used Group By clause in my soql query [SELECT  gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c,sum(gmod__Price__c) gmod__Price__c ,SUm(gmod__Amount__c) gmod__Amount__c,Sum(gmod__Quantity__c) gmod__Qunatity__c,COUNT(id) Quantity FROM gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c WHERE  gmod__date__c=THIS_FISCAL_YEAR GROUP BY  gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c];but at the gmod__date__c its not accepting the Last Fiscal year .It doesnot gives the o/p and the grandtotal is not dispalyed correctly.